# Can the infinite sum of $\frac{2^{2k-1}}{5^{k+3}}$ be calculated with the formula of geometric series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to calculate the infinite sum of the series below.

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{2^{2k-1}}{5^{k+3}}$$

But unfortunately, I have no idea how to even start. Can I somehow use the formula of geometric series?

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} ar^{k} = \frac{a}{1-r}$$

If I cannot, how should I solve the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: First remove a factor $\frac 1{250}=2^{-1}5^{-3}$, then see what you can make of it...

Comment: Careful, I think the $\frac{a}{1-r}$ formula requires that the sum starts from $k=0$?

Comment: You are right, Jeppe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly, you just got to be clever. Notice:

\begin{align*}
\frac{2^{2k-1}}{5^{k+3}} &= \frac{2^{2k}}{5^k} \cdot \frac{2^{-1}}{5^3} \\
&= \frac{1}{250} \cdot \frac{4^{k}}{5^k}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Oh, okay, of course. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is not complete, as the formula can't be directly used if the lower sum is not 0. The whole thing has to be multiplied by $(\frac{4}{5})^2$ before using the formula.

Comment: True - but the OP should know to peel terms or change variables to make the formula useful.